# Pushing from Codeanywhere to Heroku - Precompiling assets failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

So I am a noob to coding. I know some html/css, but that is about it. Anyways, I am following the instructions in this poorly formatted ebook on Ruby on Rails. I have set up a container project on codeanywhere. So far I have fixed all errors up to this point through searching. It seems like a lot of people are having this problem, but I have not found a solution. I am trying to push to my Heroku account. Can anyone figure out what I am doing wrong by looking at the log? So far I have added config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false to my application.rb file because that was one of the potential fixes. Otherwise, I'm lost.

```
-----> Ruby app detected

-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails

-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.4.4

-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2

       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment

       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........

       Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

       Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.

       Fetching rake 12.3.1

       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.0.5

       Fetching json 1.8.6

       Installing rake 12.3.1

       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5

       Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions

       Fetching minitest 5.11.3

       Installing minitest 5.11.3

       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6

       Fetching builder 3.2.3

       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6

       Installing builder 3.2.3

       Fetching erubis 2.7.0

       Installing erubis 2.7.0

       Fetching rack 1.5.5

       Installing rack 1.5.5

       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.0

       Installing mini_mime 1.0.0

       Fetching arel 5.0.1.20140414130214

       Using bundler 1.15.2

       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2

       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214

       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2

       Fetching execjs 2.7.0

       Installing execjs 2.7.0

       Fetching thor 0.20.0

       Installing thor 0.20.0

       Fetching diff-lcs 1.3

       Fetching hike 1.2.3

       Installing hike 1.2.3

       Installing diff-lcs 1.3

       Fetching multi_json 1.13.1

       Installing multi_json 1.13.1

       Fetching mini_portile2 2.3.0

       Fetching pg 0.17.1

       Installing mini_portile2 2.3.0

       Installing pg 0.17.1 with native extensions

       Fetching tilt 1.4.1

       Installing tilt 1.4.1

       Fetching rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5

       Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.5

       Fetching rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5

       Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.5

       Fetching rdoc 4.3.0

       Installing rdoc 4.3.0

       Fetching rspec-support 3.8.0

       Installing rspec-support 3.8.0

       Fetching sass 3.2.19

       Installing sass 3.2.19

       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.1.0

       Installing turbolinks-source 5.1.0

       Fetching i18n 0.9.5

       Installing i18n 0.9.5

       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.5

       Installing tzinfo 1.2.5

       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3

       Installing rack-test 0.6.3

       Fetching mail 2.7.0

       Installing mail 2.7.0

       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1

       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1

       Fetching uglifier 4.1.17

       Installing uglifier 4.1.17

       Fetching nokogiri 1.8.4

       Installing nokogiri 1.8.4 with native extensions

       Fetching sprockets 2.12.5

       Installing sprockets 2.12.5

       Fetching rails_12factor 0.0.2

       Installing rails_12factor 0.0.2

       Fetching rspec-core 3.8.0

       Installing rspec-core 3.8.0

       Fetching rspec-expectations 3.8.1

       Installing rspec-expectations 3.8.1

       Fetching rspec-mocks 3.8.0

       Installing rspec-mocks 3.8.0

       Fetching turbolinks 5.1.1

       Installing turbolinks 5.1.1

       Fetching rspec 3.8.0

       Installing rspec 3.8.0

       Fetching activesupport 4.1.6

       Fetching sdoc 0.4.2

       Installing sdoc 0.4.2

       Installing activesupport 4.1.6

       Fetching actionview 4.1.6

       Fetching activemodel 4.1.6

       Fetching jbuilder 2.6.4

       Installing activemodel 4.1.6

       Installing jbuilder 2.6.4

       Installing actionview 4.1.6

       Fetching activerecord 4.1.6

       Installing activerecord 4.1.6

       Fetching actionpack 4.1.6

       Installing actionpack 4.1.6

       Fetching actionmailer 4.1.6

       Fetching railties 4.1.6

       Fetching sprockets-rails 2.3.3

       Installing actionmailer 4.1.6

       Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.3

       Installing railties 4.1.6

       Fetching jquery-rails 3.1.5

       Fetching rails 4.1.6

       Fetching coffee-rails 4.0.1

       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1

       Fetching sass-rails 4.0.5

       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.5

       Installing sass-rails 4.0.5

       Installing rails 4.1.6

       Bundle complete! 15 Gemfile dependencies, 54 gems now installed.

       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.

       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.

       Bundle completed (22.78s)

       Cleaning up the bundler cache.

-----> Installing node-v8.10.0-linux-x64

-----> Detecting rake tasks

-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline

       Running: rake assets:precompile

       /tmp/build_08716fff5e55005d68d2f9475e33fcff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Fixnum is deprecated

       /tmp/build_08716fff5e55005d68d2f9475e33fcff/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.6/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121: warning: constant ::Bignum is deprecated

       Segmentation fault (core dumped)

 !

 !     Precompiling assets failed.

 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

 !     Push failed
```

Comment: this normally happens when you have wrong css/js code on your asset files, so you need to debug those assets to see if you see some syntax error there

Comment: `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` this is not a normal thing to see during rake assets precompile. This is likely the fault of a native extension going haywire somewhere. Try to upgrade all your gems with a native extension.

Answer (score 0):

Type `$ RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` locally
Let me know if this does work?